# Partial derivatives of cost function using generalized logistic function as a predictor

Tags: regression, logistic, gradient-descent, optimization

I am trying to fit a generalized logistic function to a dataset and am having trouble computing the partial derivatives with respect to each of the variables. My cost function is as follows:

$$
 J(\theta) =\sum _{i=1}^m\left(y_{i}\:-\:k\cdot \left(\frac{1}{1+10^{A\cdot \left(B\:-x_i\right)}}\right)\right)^2
$$

And I am trying to compute $\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial k}$, $\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial A}$ and $\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial B}$ but while I managed to get $\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial k} = 2K*\left<H,H \right> - 2 * \left<H,Y\right>$ through some linear algebra (and a tutorial I found on the Web) I can't seem to be able to compute the other ones. Could anyone guide me through one of them, or point me towards a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computing $\partial_a J$ and $\partial_b J$ is not harder than the derivative with respect to $k$. You just need to apply the chain rule (since we are looking at a composite function); e.g. for $a$,

$\partial_a J = \partial_H J \; \partial_a H$

where $h_i = h(a,b,x_i) = 1 / \left(1 + 10^{\, a \, (b-x_i)}\right)$ and $H = \{h_i\}, \forall i$, if $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Or are you interested in a set of vector parameters, as in  $h(A, B, x_i) = 1 / \left( 1 + 10^{\langle A,\, B-x_i\rangle}\right)$, where $x_i, A, B \in \mathbb{R}^m$   ?

For the latter case, I get

$\partial_{a_j}\, h_i = (B - x_i)_j \, \xi(A, B, x_i)$

$\partial_{b_j}\, h_i = a_j \, \xi(A, B, x_i)$
where $\xi(A, B, x_i) = - \frac{ \ln(10) \, 10^{\langle A, B-x_i\rangle}}{\left( 1+10^{\langle A, B-x_i\rangle} \right)^2}$, $\forall j \in {1 .. m}$

Comment: $H$ is a vector built from $h(x) = \frac{1}{1 + 10^{A(B-x_i)}}$ which I separated from the original prediction function in order to reformulate the cost function as $||KH - Y||^2$. I guess my calculus is just out of shape because I have been stuck on this for the past few hours.

Comment: @jjanssen Edited, HTH !

Comment: Why is there a j index in the partial derivatives?

Comment: I made this up because you didn't specify the dimensionality of the parameters $A, B$ (and therefore of $k$ and $x_i$). Are they scalars or vectors or what else? If they are scalars forget about $j$ (i.e. A and B and $x_i$ have a single component respectively).

Comment: My bad, A, B and k are scalars

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer, I will try to see if I can work my way to them by myself!

Comment: Good luck with your project! What language are you using for this?

Comment: Thank you! I am using C#, and using L-BFGS algorithm to fit my data, which requires me to calculate the gradient of my cost function.

Comment: Actually I still have one question: why did the overall summation disappear when differentiating over A or B? I thought that the summation rule meant that the differentiation of a sum became a sum of differentials?

Comment: It certainly does; I only wrote the generic entry of the $\partial_a H$ term; you still need to multiply by $\partial_H J$, which is essentially what you got for $\partial_k J$ (also, advice for the future when manipulating these things, try to write vectors in lowercase and matrices in uppercase, along with all the respective dimensions: it also serves as a sanity check for the result)